# Vue3 carousel doesn't work smoothly when the iPhone is rotated

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, vue3-carousel

I use the vue3-carousel package in my vue project.(v0.3.1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-carousel

I implemented a simple carousel with the following code;

App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Carousel, Slide, Pagination } from 'vue3-carousel'
import 'vue3-carousel/dist/carousel.css'
</script>

<template>
  <div class="myContainer">
    <carousel :items-to-show="1">
      <slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide"> Slide index {{ slide }} </slide>

      <template #addons>
        <navigation />
        <pagination />
      </template>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.myContainer {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
}
</style>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My error case is like the following;

1- I can use the carousel well in the portrait mode of my iPhone simulator the device

2- After I change the device orientation to portrait it doesn't properly.

3- After the other orientation changes it still doesn't work well.

[I attached a demo video to the link](https://imgur.com/kylqcfN)

It seems about container fixed position but I don't understand why fixed position couses   and what this parameter breaks. Thanks.